# MFC || onDraw Image png and move it

Tags: c++, mfc, ondraw

I have created a Single Document project.

I would like to know if there is a way to make a "moving" object in MFC (CImage).

```
CcpPongView::CcpPongView() noexcept
{
    // TODO: add construction code here
    BackgdoundImage.Load(_T("background.png"));

}

    void CcpPongView::OnDraw(CDC* dc)
{

    FlickerFreeDC pDC(dc);
    CcpPongDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    
    BackgdoundImage.Draw(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0);
    ball.getBallImage().Draw(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), ball.position.x, ball.position.y, 25, 25);
    Invalidate();
}
```

but when we run this code again when it gets to the Draw function the program crash.

The project is Pong(the old game) i`m trying to make a ball moving and 2 paddles I got all the logic behind, but sadly don't know how to display it..

Please help me with this cant find it anywhere....

Comment: A program doesn't crash without reporting the failure. What is it?

Comment: `Invalidate()` inside `OnDraw()` makes no sense, it will cause another `WM_PAINT` message (mapped to `OnDraw()`) to be sent! Not that this is why your program crashes though...

Comment: @con `WM_PAINT` isn't sent. It's posted (or generated, rather). Calling `Invalidate()` from a `WM_PAINT` handler is just a simple way to implement an animation. Input messages have higher priority, so there's no opportunity for the rendering code to forego input handling.

Comment: @IInspectable : Hey the crash is "Expression: hBitmap == m_hBitmap"
and WM_PAINT i sadly i didnt know it exist, I will try to look it up :)

ConstantineGeorgiou : Hey im sorry i looked for it on the internet and it looked like it will fit there, im really not sure how am i suppose to do a loop on OnDraw and if its even needed or do i need to do the loop inside the ball class :\

Comment: That is not a crash. It is a failed debug assertion. The dialog has [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertion-failed-dialog-box) on how to proceed.

Comment: What does `ball.getBallImage()` return? Couls you pleaseshow the code?